# How do you select an image that was just pasted to MS Word via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Just pasted an image to MS Word in VBA using the following

```
wordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine
```

My thinking is to move one char left and then select next object, but I don't know how to do this.

EDIT:

Well here are some encoraging development, using the following line, I was able to select the paragraph which include the image, but I can't manipulate it because it's selecting a range.  Do anyone know how I can pin down the image inside the selection?

```
wordApp.Selection.Expand wdParagraph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I used:

```
wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute replace:=2
wordApp.Selection.Expand wdParagraph
wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also doing the same. It seems that after pasting an image into word, its already selected. You can just use the selected object with the simple code below:

```
Selection.InlineShapes(1).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used VBA in Word but here's a quick thought.  If you're pasting the image inline and immediately trying to get a reference it should be the last item in the InlineShapes collection.  This code will give you a reference you can use:

`thisDocument.InlineShapes(thisDocument.InlineShapes.Count)`

For example, to set the width of last pasted image you would use the following:

```
thisDocument.InlineShapes(thisDocument.InlineShapes.Count).Width = 100
```

To store the shape in a variable:

```
Dim pastedImage As InlineShape

Set pastedImage = ThisDocument.InlineShapes(ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count)
```

Comment: Hi Banjoe

I actually used a different method to reference it but I think yours work too.

Comment: This method works perfectly for me as I'm pasting and modifying images one by one. Thanks! +1

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not reliable.  This approach failed when working with inline shapes within Word tables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to use the property "AlternativeText" to mark the pasted shapes as old, so whenever a shape is not old it has to be the New one.

I use the following:

```
Dim pShape as InLineShape' The shape i'm looking for
Dim iShape as InlineShape

For Each iShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If iShape.AlternativeText = "" Then
        Set pShape = iShape
        pShape.AlternativeText = "old"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Not very clean, but in VBA is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mark the element left from your cursor position:

```
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
```